# A modern rhyme, paying respect to history

Tags: wordplay, history

Secret stationary falls bitter,
cross like purge,
princess piic.

They all pay tribute to me.

> Who am I?

Hint 1:

> The rhyme that doesn't rhyme:
> secrets
> Station
> Falls
> Bitter
> Cross
> Lake
> perch
> princess
> Peak

Hint 2:

> I am a historical person

Comment: what is a piic?

Comment: It is tagged wordplay...

Comment: ok @Enigma tag this rhyme as well

Comment: But it doesn't rhyme...

Comment: Cross-like Purge - Nazi Genocide?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

are you:

> Queen Victoria (or more simply Victoria)

as in:

> Victoria secrets (the Store), Victoria Station (London train station), Victoria Falls (waterfall), Victoria Bitter (VB, Australian beer), Victoria Cross (military award), lake victoria, victoria peak (HK) and so on...